# Reference to a non-shared member settings error

Tags: vb.net, settings, appsettings

I have added a settings file to a project but whenever I reference one of the setting variables I get the following error:

```
Error   2   Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference.  C:\Development\PhoenixApp\Process\CreditCardProcessing.vb   67  77  Process
```

I had to manually add this in a merge conflict and the settings code worked fine in the originating branch.  The generated code also seems to be identical from what I can see.

I am accessing the settings using  `My.Settings.{VarName}`

edit: Just tried deleting the settings files. This still happens once the file has been re-generated from the app.config values.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this happens.

But if you go to the definition of `My.Settings` that property should return a reference to a `Shared ReadOnly Property` called `[Default]` in Settings.Designer.vb and that property returns the `Shared` member called `defaultInstance`.

I'd suggest trying to go back to the definitions in your code (right click on `My.Settings` and select `Go To Definition`) and make sure that it's the same for you.

Comment: The property is as follows:
    Public Shared ReadOnly Property [Default]() As 
        Get
            Return defaultInstance
        End Get
    End Property

Comment: @themainin: Looks ok. I suggest editing your question to add a minimal code sample showing the bits of code where it's failing.